# Issue for Kurento one2many webRTC video streaming using RTSP steam as source

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I have done the code changes by referring "kurento-one2many-call" node sample for webRTC video streaming using RTSP steam as source. Code is available on [***GitHub Repository***](https://github.com/Nileshwagh22/Kurento-rtsp-one-to-many). Presenter/source(***PlayerEndpoint***) is loaded on start of node application, and viewer will stream video stream by clicking on viewer button. No need to add presenter or click on presenter button.

But I am facing problem with this code, When I will click on viewer button, no any error on Chrome console log and on Firefox it shows "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details" error on console log. It just showing spinner and video did not get displayed.

If we monitor Node log, then everything is fine with it, PlayerEndpoint is created successfully and responding to ICE messages. Last line of log is printed as ***"Sending viewer candidate."*** after that it will stuck, nothing will be printed later. Same will happen for new viewer request.

Please help me to get out of this issue, or suggest me any code changes.

Comment: Is your KMS server deployed behind NAT? If that's the case, you'll need a STUN server.

Comment: @igracia.   I have enabled the STUN server from "WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini", But still same issue is there. I have monitor Media Server log, I found  "remove_not_supported_codecs_from_array()"  line in it. Full log file on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cUXiWXjs). Is this line creates issue? Please give me some suggestion for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The STUN server you have configured in your WebRtcEndpoint.ini (173.194.66.127) is not generating any candidates. It's very likely that the server is down. Please use any other publicly available STUN server from [this](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933) list. Also, don't forget to check that the server is indeed working by any of the following methods

- Via the [Trickle ICE test page](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/). Don't forget to remove the existing STUN server.
- In your KMS box, through the [`stun`](https://serverfault.com/a/43090) command. You might need to install the package via `sudo apt-get install stun`

Comment: Thanks @igracia. I have resolved this issue, actually problem was with Nodejs code.

Comment: Good to know! In any case, check that STUN server, as it didn't give any candidates when I tested it.

Comment: I am able to stream(RTSP as source and WebRTC destination to Browser) RTSP stream as H264 but problem with RTSP stream with MP2T transport. Can Kurento support MP2T transport to convert into VP8? If not, then please can you suggest any solution for it.